# Does a target affected by font of radiance get to save before it takes damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

> #### Font of Radiance
>
> Epic Tier
>
> **Prerequisite:** 21st level
>
> **Benefit:** When you score a critical hit with a power that has the radiant keyword, the target begins to glow brightly (save ends).
>
> The target’s space and all squares adjacent to it are illuminated by bright light. Invisible creatures become visible while they are in affected squares, and attack rolls against creatures in those squares take no penalty for concealment. Any foe that ends its turn in an affected square (including the original target) takes 3d6 radiant damage.

Does the target I made a critical hit against that is being affected by the font of radiance power get to save before being affected by the damage? End of turn effects are chosen in order by the enemy.

In addition, if the target does take 3d6 radiant damage and if he is already vulnerable to radiant by another source... do I gain the extra damage from Pelor's Sun Blessing with the following property?

> Property:  If you deal damage to a target that has vulnerability to radiant damage, you deal extra damage equal to your Wisdom or Constitution modifier, whichever is higher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, the target can attempt to save before the damage takes place.**

From the Rules Compendium, page 198-199:

> **The End of a Turn**
>
> *Any Order:* The creature can choose the order in which things happen at the end of its turn. For instance, if the creature has saving throws to make and is subjected to an effect that damages it at the end of its turn, the creature can choose to take the damage and then make the saving throws or the other way around.

There's almost no reason for the target to take the damage before trying to save, so it will usually attempt to save against the effect before it takes the damage.

To clarify: if the target successfully saves, it does *not* take the damage.

**Yes, you would gain the extra damage from Pelor's Sun Blessing.**

If you have the Font of Radiance feat, then you are considered the source for any damage the feat deals, so you would gain the extra damage from Pelor's Sun Blessing whenever a Font of Radiance you caused deals damage to a foe vulnerable to radiant damage.